Simulate effect of power supply noise on op amp - LTspice
I want to see how power supply noise affects op amps output. To do so I use LTspice simulations. My power supplies look like this: . And for the op amp I use TI instruments OPA211 spice model. For example: .
My circuit is more complicated than a single op amp, but when I run a noise analysis like so: .noise V(OUTPUT) V1 dec 10 0.1 100e3, the result does not seem to depend on the noise of the power supplies, even when there are no decoupling capacitors as suggested in TI's datasheets.
Q: What is the correct way of measuring the effect of power supply noise on op amps using LTspice?

Do you know if the SPICE model has PSRR rejection included in the model? Look in the model file and look at the comments. Sometimes model files will have comments saying what the model does and doesn't do.

In the model (https://www.ti.com/lit/zip/sbombw8) I have, it is written: * Model Usage Notes:



The following parameters are modeled:


a. OPEN-LOOP GAIN AND PHASE VS. FREQUENCY  WITH RL, CL EFFECTS (Aol)
....
d. POWER SUPPLY REJECTION RATIO VS. FREQUENCY (PSRR)

So I think it should be encoded in there, although I have no idea how these models actually work and how to check it is effectiveley working....

Nice that the model is fairly detailed.
Noise analysis will report thermal and other noise mechanisms of the various components. It will not report noise from a voltage source since the output resistance is zero.
Below is an example of playing about with PSRR. You can do either an AC or Transient analysis. The graph is edited to show both AC and Transient analysis. The device used is the opamp2 model where you need to supply a model which is called out in the .include card. The inset at bottom right shows how you fill in the Value parameter for U1.

V3 is to provide verification that the circuit is working as an amplifier. For the PSRR analysis, V3 is set to zero. It can be eliminated and replaced with a short once you are sure your circuit and model are behaving as expected.
I used a sine wave source for the power supply noise to verify that the Transient and .AC analyses behave as expected. You can replace V1 & V4 with a noise source if so desired.
You need to be careful with practical integrator circuits as the DC gain becomes the open loop gain of the opamp (many millions). Any input bias voltages will be greatly amplified. You will need to place a resistor across the integrator capacitor, the value depending on what your requirements are.
A nit to pick: Opamps shown as boxes are discouraged as they are difficult for experienced engineers to comprehend. In the future, please use the more traditional opamp symbol. Also, ground symbols point downward, not up or sideways. Conventions make schematics easier to read.

Thanks for the great answer, I always wondered about the ground direction.

To be clear you're saying there is no way of looking at the effect of power supply noise on the output of an op amp with the noise command

@DarkBulle The .noise command analyzes noise generated by components and not sources. So just the stuff inside the opamp and any resistors around the opamp (unless you flag them as noiseless).
